# How to open another activity when emulator is rotated in android studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, accelerometer

I am using the accelerometer sensor that checks the value of x,y & z(directions) whenever emulator is rotated. Now, how can I switch to another activity whenever mobile is rotated in any direction?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float values[]= event.values;
    float accx = values[0];
    float accy = values[1];
    float accz = values[2];
    t1.setText("X: "+(int)accx);
    t2.setText("Y: "+(int)accy);
    t3.setText("Z: "+(int)accz);

    if(accx<-9){
        Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(s);
    }/*
    else if(accy<-9){
        Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(s);
    }
    else if(accx>9){
        Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main4Activity.class);
        startActivity(s);
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```